# Flutter list .add function null

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> finallist() async {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> finallist;

    Future createList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) async {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> listoflocationforsingle = snapshot.documents;
      for (DocumentSnapshot u in listoflocationforsingle) {
        print('Added ' + u.data['country']);
        finallist.add(u);
      }
    }
```

finallist.add(u) fails with add on null error.

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'))
```

Even tho when I hover over the data in createlist(data), it shows list of QuerySnapshot with the data in my firestore database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, my future function actually does it. Just that I needed to add in

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> finallist = []; // add in the ' = [] '
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single query that can get data from multiple subcollections.  Firestore queries are shallow, and only work with documents within a single collection at a time.  If you want data from three subcollections, you will need to be three queries, one for each subcollection.